# Cocoapods: Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

Unable to install pods in the project.

Getting the following error:
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/comp-user/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

I tried using pod install command but failed to install pods.

Answer (score 1):

This may also happen if you've installed a new update of macOS or Xcode, and have not opened Xcode to install additional components.
If that's the case, just open Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Add `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' in your pod file.

E.g.:

....
platform :ios, '11.0'

**source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'**

target 'ProjectTech' do 
use_frameworks! 
....

This resolves the above issue.